Extract the curent username C# , Forms
I made an application in Winforms c# with ado net and it has a form for creating an account but also for logging in, the idea is that after a person enters his data and creates his account or logs in, his name should appear on the next form , and this should come from the database, the idea is that I don't know how to do this, I read and searched on the net only that what the net gives me is the name on Windows of the person and not of the person who logged in, if you can give me any idea, thank you very much.

 string nameUser;
 public string ExtractCurrentUserName()
 {

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         string interrogation = "SELECT (Username) FROM USERS WHERE Username = @Username";
         connection.Open();
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(interrogation, connection);
         string currentName= System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];

         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", currentName);

         using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 nameUser = (string)reader["Username"];
             }
         }
     }

     return nameUser;
 }



Don't post code as an image.

well, how else to post it ? l

@AlexandraA as text, but use some formatting to make code look like code (see markdown). Share only relevant code and try make minimal reproducible example

Look carefully to your sql text. You need the username to build the paramenter for the command. Then you execute the command to search for the username passed as parameter. What's the point?


By "forms" do you mean web forms or winforms? 2) By "logging in" are you talking about Windows authentication or some sort of application login (e.g. logging in to your web site?)


Winforms forms, by login I mean when they fill in the login data and give login

EDIT: You provided code in text, instead of image:
string currentName= System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];

No need  to search the database for the name. The current username is available straight from the identity object.

i post the photo as a image

You need to provide an error, somewhere where your code doesn't perform as expected.
Along with a description of what you expected to happened, and what did actually happen.
The error message should be either an exception or a compiler error provided by the IDE.
Your question is still not giving us enough information to actually help you.
